# Need help evaluating double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need help calculating $I$ where:
$$I = \iint_R\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} 
,\qquad R = \left\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 -x \le 0 , y \ge 0  \right\}$$

The possible answers are

1. $\:\pi$
2. $\:2\pi-1$
3. $\:2\pi+2$
4. $\:\pi +1$

I have converted it to polar where I ended up with the integral:
$$I = \int_0^\pi\int_0^{cos{\theta}}\frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\:dr\:d\theta$$

I have tried evauluating it but the answer I get is: $\:\pi -2$

I took the following steps:

1. $\int_0^{\cos\theta}\frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}} ,\:u = 1-r^2,\: dr = \frac{-1}{2r}du$
2. $\int_0^{\cos\theta}\frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}} =\int \frac{r}{\sqrt{u}}\frac{-1}{2r}du = \frac{-1}{2}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}du  = \frac{-1}{2}\left[2\sqrt{1-r^2} \right]_0^{\cos\theta} = -\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta} \:\:+ 1 $
3. $-\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta} \:\:+ 1  = 1 - \sin\theta$
4. $\int_0^\pi 1- \sin\theta \:d\theta = \int_0^\pi1\:d\theta + \int_0^\pi -\sin\theta \:d\theta$
5. $\int_0^\pi1\:d\theta = \pi$
6. $\int_0^\pi -\sin\theta \:d\theta = \left[ \cos\theta\right]_0^\pi = \cos(\pi) - \cos(0) = -2$
7. From steps 4, 5 and 6 we get $\:I = \pi -2$

Somewhere along these steps I have made a mistake and I can't find it.

Comment: Actually, the correct answer is $\frac\pi2-1$.

Comment: First comment.  $\cos\theta < 0$ when $\theta > \pi/2$.

Comment: Which quadrants does the circle $r=\cos\theta$ live in? It doesn't include the angle $\pi$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

To begin with, notice that:
\begin{align*}
R & = \left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid \left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} + y^{2} \leq \frac{1}{4}\right\}\cap\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid y\geq 0\}
\end{align*}
which can be written in polar coordinates as (according to the cosine's law):
\begin{align*}
R = \left\{(r,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\times[0,2\pi) \mid (0\leq r\leq \cos(\theta)) \wedge (0\leq \theta\leq \pi/2)\right\}
\end{align*}

[image]

Consequently the proposed integral corresponds to:
\begin{align*}
\iint_{R}\frac{\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{1 - x^{2} - y^{2}}} & = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\cos(\theta)}\frac{r}{\sqrt{1 - r^{2}}}\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta\\\\
\end{align*}
whence I guess you can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The region $R$ is the upper half of the disk centered at $\left(\frac12,0\right)$ with radius $\frac12$. It's part of the right half-plane $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x\geqslant0\}$, and therefore, when you use polar coordinates, the range of $\theta$ can be $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ at most. But, since $R$ also consists only of points $(x,y)$ with $y\geqslant0$, it's not hard to see that $\theta$ can only takes values on $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$. So, the integral is equal to$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\cos\theta}\frac\rho{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac\pi2-1.$$You can also do it without polar coordinates:\begin{align}\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{x-x^2}}\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx&=\int_0^1\arctan\left(\sqrt x\right)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\frac\pi2-1.\end{align}